# UI-Router 's on stateChangeStar Only fires Once

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I set up my App.run method as follows:

```
 $rootScope.AuthBag = { Authenticated: false, User: "", Roles:[] };
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (toState.authenticate && ($rootScope.AuthBag.Authenticated === false)) {
                $rootScope.returnToState = toState.url;
                $rootScope.returnToStateParams = toParams.Id;
                $location.path('/Site/LogOn');                      
            }           
    });
```

But this works only once and when first loads. my States are:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Site/Movies");

.state('site.movies', {
    url: "/Movies",             
    templateUrl: "/Views/Site/movies.html",
    controller: 'moviesController',
    authenticate: true
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this does not make future trouble but:

```
window.location = "/Site/LogOn";
```

Solved my problem.